# How to post html data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http-post

I need to grab a table's html and post it to a page where the table will be exported as xls,
but I can't get it to work, I tried to pass the data as object, no luck, then I tried to pass it as string, still no luck (is it because the table too large?)

```
        //var tblReportResultData= "id=tblReportResult&name=tblReportResult&html=" + escape($("#tblReportResult").html()); //,
        var tblReportResultData = {id:"check",html:$("#tblReportResult").html()}

        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.aspx',
            type:'POST',
            data:tblReportResultData,
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(msg){
                alert("waterver");
            },
            error: function(xhr, text, err){
                alert("Error:" + text);
            }                
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked for warnings on net console of firebug

Comment: in the net console, it says 500 Internal Server Error. I tried to pass the data as string but replaced html=talbehtml to html=averyshortstring, it worked, any idea? is it because the html string too large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, it's because post html code could be dangerous and the system automatically blocked it, after I used escape(), it worked.